# serialize form in jquery after elements adding

Tags: jquery, serialization

I'm dynamic add some inputs to my form by changing html() of some divs located in form. When i'm them serialaze this form inserted inputs doesn't serialized. what can i do?

Comment: Can you post an example?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the new elements have unique names and IDs.